# How to Convert hashmap into proper json format in mule 4?

Tags: java, mule, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I am trying to log my hashmap it looks something like this :
[image]

How do I convert it into proper json format ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Transform Component and write the dataweave code as follows:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload pluck(message,property,index) -> {(index) :{(property) :message}}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 4):

Just add a transform message at the end of flow with

```
%dw2.0
application/json
---
payload
```